# local laravel website redirecting to production server

Tags: php, laravel, wamp

When I try to connect to the local version of the site hosted on WAMP, I get redirected to the live version of the site, even after changing the `APP_URL`, `APP_NAME` and `APP_ENV`in the `.env` file.
Is there any reason as to why such behaviour can occur ? How can I prevent it ?

Comment: Have you cached the settings after changing env?

Comment: Check your .htaccess file, maybe you have the redirection codes.

Comment: There is mutliple possibilities :
Are the .env value cached ? try
    php artisan cache:clear

Answer (score 0):

Solved by editing the .htaccess like  jogesh_pi suggested.

Comment: what changes you have done in .htaccess file

Answer (score 0):

By running this 4 command you can solve it..

php artisan cache:clear

php artisan route:clear

php artisan config:clear

php artisan view:clear